# Autocompleting of float input control in Jasperserver

Tags: jasperserver

I am trying to add input control which accepts float input values, I have a problem with autocompleting of input control. For example, if the input control is given value: 1.3 [before click on accept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3AAp.png) it's completed (or rounded?) to strange value: [after click on accept button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2hSV.png).

The problem happens with floating point numbers, but not for the full number(like 1.0).

Thanks in advance!

Tried to change type of input controls, and cast them to float but didnt work